# Spark Streaming application fails with KafkaException: String exceeds the maximum size or with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-1.6

TL;DR:

My very simple Spark Streaming application fails in the driver with the "KafkaException: String exceeds the maximum size". I see the same exception in the executor but I also found somewhere down the executor's logs an IllegalArgumentException with no other information in it

Full problem:

I'm using Spark Streaming to read some messages from a Kafka topic.
This is what I'm doing:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("testName")
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(new SparkContext(conf), Milliseconds(millis))
val kafkaParams = Map(
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "somevalidaddresshere:9092",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest"
    )
val topics = Set("data")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      streamingContext,
      kafkaParams,
      topics
    ).map(_._2) // only need the values not the keys
```

What I'm doing with the Kafka data is only printing it using:

```
stream.print()
```

My application obviously has more code than this but in order to locate my problem I stripped everything I possibly could from the code

I'm trying to run this code on YARN.
This is my spark submit line:

```
./spark-submit --class com.somecompany.stream.MainStream --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster myjar.jar hdfs://some.hdfs.address.here/user/spark/streamconfig.properties
```

The streamconfig.properties file is just a regular properties file which is probably irrelevant to the problem here

After trying to execute the application it fails pretty quickly with the following exception on the driver:

```
16/05/10 06:15:38 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, some.hdfs.address.here): kafka.common.KafkaException: String exceeds the maximum size of 32767.
    at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.shortStringLength(ApiUtils.scala:73)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$.headerSize(FetchResponse.scala:107)
    at kafka.api.TopicData.<init>(FetchResponse.scala:113)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:103)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:170)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't even see my code in the stack trace

Examining the executor I found the same exception as in the driver but also buried deep down is the following exception:

```
16/05/10 06:40:47 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponsePartitionData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:38)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$$anonfun$1.apply(FetchResponse.scala:100)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$$anonfun$1.apply(FetchResponse.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.TopicData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:98)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:170)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponse$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:169)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have no idea what is the IllegalArgument since no information is included

The Spark version my YARN is using is 1.6.0. I also verified my pom contains Spark 1.6.0 and not an earlier version. My scope is "provided"

I manually read the data from the exact same topic and the data there is just plain JSONs. The data there is not huge at all. Definitely smaller than 32767. Also I'm able to read this data using the regular command line consumer so that's weird

Googling this exception sadly didn't provide any useful information

Does anyone have any idea on how to understand what exactly is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the topic in the question ("data") the actual topic name you are using? Following the stack trace in the source code, it's the validation of the topic length that fails in this case.

Comment: Nope, I modified it for the question, the real topic name is just a regular string though, the same one I'm using when accessing it from the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging I think I found what the problem was. I'm running Spark on YARN (1.6.0-cdh5.7.0). Cloudera has the new Kafka client (0.9 version) which had an inter protocol change from the earlier versions. However, our Kafka is of version 0.8.2.