# Cannot read from Kafka with Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I'm having hard time getting Spark to read from Kafka on Cloudera 5.7. I ended up using the spark-shell directly, trying various ways and various versions of Kafka.

**1. I raise the spark-shell this way:**

```
spark-shell --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 500M --num-executors 1
```

**2. In the shell, I use the simple scala code just to get the topic messages in the [direct way](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers):**

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import _root_.kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder
import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

val kafkaParams = Map(
    "zookeeper.connect" -> "cloudera-host:2181",
    "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-test",
    "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "1000",
    "metadata.broker.list" -> "cloudera-host:9092"
)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val topics = Set("mytopic")

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

val pairs = messages.map(tuple2 => tuple2._2)

pairs.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**3. The program seems fine until I feed the topic with data:**

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list cloudera-host:9092 --topic mytopic < ~/some_log_file
```

**4. After that, following exception occurs:**

```
16/12/27 19:01:59 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, cloudera-host): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
at kafka.api.FetchResponsePartitionData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:38)
at kafka.api.TopicData$$anonfun$1.apply(FetchResponse.scala:100)
at kafka.api.TopicData$$anonfun$1.apply(FetchResponse.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at kafka.api.TopicData$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:98)
at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:170)
at kafka.api.FetchResponse$$anonfun$4.apply(FetchResponse.scala:169)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at kafka.api.FetchResponse$.readFrom(FetchResponse.scala:169)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From what i googled, it might be related to Kafka and Spark version mismatch. I'm using Cloudera's Kafka kafka_0.9.0+kafka2.0.1-1.2.0.1.p0.5~trusty-kafka2.0.1_all.deb which should work with provided Spark 1.6.1. I have also tried other CL packages containing Kafka 0.9. Spark is running on Yarn.

Comment: I think Spark 1.6.1 supports Kafka 0.8 only. Can you post the entire logs on gist or similar to review?

Comment: Hi Jacek, thanks. I actually installed Kafka 0.8 just to be shure, and same exception occurrs. Yarn log is here: http://pastebin.com/fKzRAiXj, console text is here: http://pastebin.com/pkLB8RuW. Now these logs are with Kafka 0.8 but it happens also with 0.9

Comment: Can you please check if http://stackoverflow.com/q/37131580/1305344 helps?

Comment: If I understand that link, the solution is to install Kafka 0.9., however I already did that. Apart the version 0.8.2, I tried kafka_0.9.0+kafka2.0.0, kafka_0.9.0+kafka2.0.1 and kafka_0.9.0+kafka2.0.2. I will investigate a bit more and report back if I resolve it.